# How to check that an environment variable is non-empty in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, environment-variables, ansible-2.x

I'd like to check that an environment variable is defined and non-empty in Ansible 2.9. If it's empty or undefined, I'd like to `fail` in the role. Therefore I need to pass an expression to the `when` parameter of `fail`. However, I'm not able to figure out what I need to pass. I tried

```
- fail:
    msg: "Environment variable ENV_VAR is not defined or empty"
    when: lookup('env', "ENV_VAR") | length > 0
```

```
- fail:
    msg: "Environment variable ENV_VAR is not defined or empty"
    when: (lookup('env', "ENV_VAR") | length) > 0
```

```
- fail:
    msg: "Environment variable ENV_VAR is not defined or empty"
    when: "{{(lookup('env', 'ENV_VAR') | length) > 0}}"
```

```
- fail:
    msg: "Environment variable ENV_VAR is not defined or empty"
    when: lookup('env', 'ENV_VAR') == ''
```

All approaches fail due to

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Invalid options for fail: when"}
```

and the [documentation of `env`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/env.html) as well as [`fail`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/fail_module.html) contain no clue for me what `when` expects.

I'd be thankful for both a fix and explanation for the usege of `fail` or a different solution to the problem of checking that an environment variable is non-empty.

I saw [ansible when comparing integer values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284308/ansible-when-comparing-integer-values) where the problem was a missing cast to `int` which can't be the problem here as `length` returns an integer.

I'm using Ansible 2.9 on Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: YAML is extremely whitespace sensitive, and [as the examples show](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/fail_module.html#examples) the `when:` must be at the same level as the `name:`, since it is a [task keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task) which applies to _all_ tasks. You may also enjoy the [`assert:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/assert_module.html) module, which may be a little easier to reason about

Comment: @mdaniel Ah, so `when` needs to be on the same level as the task, no a parameter of `fail`. If you care for the points, you can post an answer. Thank you. The assert module has the same trouble with the wrong indentation which makes sense.

Comment: `assert` won't need a `when` but has a `that` parameter that would be indented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YAML is extremely whitespace sensitive, and [as the examples show](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/fail_module.html#examples) the `when:` must be at the same level as the `name:`, since [it is a task keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task) which applies to all tasks. You may also enjoy the [`assert:` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/assert_module.html), which may be a little easier to reason about